# How to decrypt data without plaintext size? - openssl encryption c++ ubuntu environment

Tags: c++, ubuntu, encryption, openssl, aes

I have the following function that decrypts ciphertexts.

However i have a problem that i would like to decrypt the data without having the plaintext length! How do i do that? As if i send a encrypted data over, it would not be appropriate to send the ciphertext with the plain-text length.

```
int main()
{
/*some code*/
char input[] = "123456789abcdef";
int olen, len;
len = strlen(input)+1;

plaintext = (char *)aes_decrypt(&de, ciphertext, &len);
/*some code*/
}
```

Decryption method

```
unsigned char *aes_decrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e, unsigned char *ciphertext, int *len)
    {
      /* plaintext will always be equal to or lesser than length of ciphertext*/
      int p_len = *len, f_len = 0;
      unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char *)malloc(p_len);

      if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(e, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)){
        printf("ERROR in EVP_DecryptInit_ex \n");
        return NULL;
      }

      if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(e, plaintext, &p_len, ciphertext, *len)){
        printf("ERROR in EVP_DecryptUpdate\n");
        return NULL;
      }

      if(!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(e, plaintext+p_len, &f_len)){
        printf("ERROR in EVP_DecryptFinal_ex\n");
        return NULL;
      }

      *len = p_len + f_len;
      return plaintext;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would prefix the cleartext with a length indicator before encryption. This can be as small as a single byte "valid bytes in last block".

Comment: Hi thanks! I guess this would work! But how abt the last part where padding is added. Will it be removed automatically?

Comment: For that to happen, the decryption routines need to understand what to cut off -- they do not assume anything about your data, because what is valid data to you might be a "cut off here" marker for someone else.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need the plaintext length - just the length of the ciphertext.

EVP can perform and handle PKCS #7 padding 'automagically', and does this by default. PKCS #7 padding works as follows: it determines how many characters of padding are needed to block-align the plaintext for encryption, and then takes that number and repeats it at the end of the plaintext that many times (in byte form).

For instance, if I have a 14-byte block of plaintext of the hexadecimal form

```
61 74 74 61 63 6b 20 61 74 20 64 61 77 6e
```

and I need to pad it to 16 bytes for encryption, I will append `02` twice to the end to get

```
61 74 74 61 63 6b 20 61 74 20 64 61 77 6e 02 02
```

If my plaintext is already aligned to a 16-byte boundary, then I add 16 bytes of `10` (i.e. 16 in hex) to the end of the plaintext. I can thus always assume that padding exists in the plaintext, removing my need to guess. EVP's routines will detect the padding after decryption and trim it off, returning the original plaintext with its correct length.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! able to give an example of how to do that? as when i do sizeof(ciphertext), it only gives me value of 4. whereas sizeof(plaintext) = 16. P.S. im doing aes encryption

Comment: @dupdupdup If you're actually looking to use AES encryption then you're missing a good chunk of code. The correct call to `EVP_EncryptInit_ex()` (and by extension `EVP_DecryptInit_ex()`) should be of the form `EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, some_key, some_iv)`. `ctx` is an allocated `EVP_CIPHER_CTX`, and `some_key` and `some_iv` are `const char *` pointing to, respectively, the 256-bit key and 128-bit initialization vector you want to use.

Comment: thanks for the info! I deliberately left them out so that i can ask the question clearly! :)